# Get original text of an Antlr rule

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I am an ANTLR beginner and want to calculate a SHA1-Hash of symbols.

My simplified example grammar:

```
grammar Example;

method @after{calculateSha1($text); }: 'call' ID;

ID: 'A'..'Z'+;
WS: (' '|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip(); }
COMMENT: '/*' (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN}
```

As the lexer removes all whitespaces the different strings `callABC`, `call /* DEF */ ABC` unfortunately get the same SHA1-Hash value.

Is it possible to get the "original" text of a rule between the start- and end-token with all the skipped whitespaces and the text of the other channels?

(One possibility that comes into my mind is to member all characters in the `WS`- and `COMMENT`-lexer rule, but there are many more rules, so this isn't very practical.)

I use the standard ANTLRInputStream to feed the Lexer, but I don't know how to receive the original text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `skip()`-ping the `WS` token, put it on the `HIDDEN` channel as well:

```
grammar Example;

@parser::members {
  void calculateSha1(String text) {
    try {
      java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      byte[] sha1 = md.digest(text.getBytes());
      System.out.println(text + "\n" + java.util.Arrays.toString(sha1) + "\n");
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

parse 
  :  method+ EOF
  ;

method
@after{calculateSha1($text);}
  :  'call' ID
  ;

ID      : 'A'..'Z'+;
WS      : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : '/*' .* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

The grammar above can be tested with:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "call ABC call /* DEF */ ABC";
    ExampleLexer lexer = new ExampleLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    ExampleParser parser = new ExampleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

which will print the following to the console:

```
call ABC
[48, -45, 113, 5, -52, -128, -78, 75, -52, -97, -35, 25, -55, 59, -85, 96, -58, 58, -96, 10]

call /* DEF */ ABC
[-57, -2, -115, -104, 77, -37, 4, 93, 116, -123, -47, -4, 33, 42, -68, -95, -43, 91, 94, 77]
```

i.e.: the same parser rule, yet different `$text`'s (and therefor different SHA1's).

Comment: Thank you very much for your ANTLR-knowledge! :-) I didn't realized that also off-channel-tokens are used to construct $text.

Comment: @Sonson, yes, if you `skip()` them, they are really removed from the lexer (and therefor from `$text` as well), but putting them on a different channel (HIDDEN or a custom channel) will only cause them to be skipped by parser rules when they "poll" the lexer for a new `Token`. Getting the `$text` from a parser rule, will also take `Token`s into account on other channels. And you're welcome.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343288/how-do-i-get-the-original-text-that-an-antlr4-rule-matched) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443728/context-gettext-excludes-spaces-in-antlr4).

Comment: @SomeGuy note that those question are related to ANTLR4, while this question and answer are about ANTLR3.