# How do I get the original text that an antlr4 rule matched?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Using the Java 7 grammar https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java7/Java7.g4 I want to find methods with a specific name and then just print out that method.  I see that I can use the `methodDeclaration` rule when I match.  So I subclass `Java7BaseListener` and override this listener method:

```
@Override public void enterMethodDeclaration(Java7Parser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) { }
```

How do I get the original text out?  `ctx.getText()` gives me a string with all the whitespace stripped out.  I want the comments and original formatting.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443860/get-original-text-of-an-antlr-rule) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443728/context-gettext-excludes-spaces-in-antlr4).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

ANTLR's `CharStream` class has a method `getText(Interval interval)` which will return the original source in the give range.  The `Context` object has methods to get the beginning and end.  Assuming you have a field in your listener called `input` which has the CharStream being parsed, you can do this:

```
    int a = ctx.start.getStartIndex();
    int b = ctx.stop.getStopIndex();
    Interval interval = new Interval(a,b);
    input.getText(interval);
```

Comment: If you don't have access to or don't want to keep track of the `CharStream`, use `ctx.start.getInputStream()` to retrieve it.

Comment: CharStream input = ctx.start.getInputStream();
input.getText(interval);

Gives me runtime errors .checkBoundsOffCount(String.java:3101)

Comment: And where it doesn't fail it still removes whitespace

Comment: Your answer helped me fix a weird error where calling `getText()` on a `Token` failed because somehow my original `CharStream` got garbage collected. I kept a reference to it and `getText` works now.

Comment: Totally nonintuitive as far as solutions go, this was a lifesaver for me.

Answer (score 14):

demo:

```
SqlBaseParser.QueryContext queryContext = context.query();
int a = queryContext.start.getStartIndex();
int b = queryContext.stop.getStopIndex();
Interval interval = new Interval(a,b);
String viewSql = context.start.getInputStream().getText(interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16343289) doesn't work when there are errors during the parsing, and antlr fixes those errors (which is the default behavior).
By default antlr uses [`DefaultErrorStrategy`](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html) which creates tokens with `startIndex=endIndex=-1` for missing tokens ([here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/v4.11.1/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.java#L599) is the source code).
The code in the accepted answer will throw an exception in case of such tokens.

Also antlr's smart error handling [can delete](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/v4.11.1/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.java#L467) some "extra" tokens.

As a result, "the matched text" can consists of multiple chunks of the original text + some tokens that have no matched original text.

Some possible solutions for this problem:

- either use `ANTLRErrorStrategy` without smart error handling (e.g. [`BailErrorStrategy`](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BailErrorStrategy.html))
- or iterate recursively over node's children and collect text from valid tokens only.

Answer (score 1):

Python implementation:

```py
def extract_original_text(self, ctx):
    token_source = ctx.start.getTokenSource()
    input_stream = token_source.inputStream
    start, stop  = ctx.start.start, ctx.stop.stop
    return input_stream.getText(start, stop)
```