# How to get the full user-written statements (including the spaces) in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I have a "statement" definition from the Java language definition as follows.

```
statement
: block
|   ASSERT expression (':' expression)? ';'
|   'if' parExpression statement ('else' statement)?
|   'for' '(' forControl ')' statement
|   'while' parExpression statement
|   'do' statement 'while' parExpression ';'
|   'try' block
    ( catches 'finally' block
    | catches
    | 'finally' block
    )
|   'switch' parExpression switchBlock
|   'synchronized' parExpression block
|   'return' expression? ';'
|   'throw' expression ';'
|   'break' Identifier? ';'
|   'continue' Identifier? ';'
|   ';'
|   statementExpression ';'
|   Identifier ':' statement
;
```

When doing the parser, i want to print the full user-written statements also (inculding the spaces in the statements),  such as:

```
Object o = Ma.addToObj(r1);
if(h.isFull() && !h.contains(true)) h.update(o);
```

But when i use the function "getText()" in "exitStatement", i can only get the statements with all the spaces been deleted, such as:

```
Objecto=Ma.addToObj(r1);
if(h.isFull()&&!h.contains(true))h.update(o);
```

How can i get the full user-written statements (inculding the spaces in the statements) in a easy way? Thanks a lot!

The full codes as follows:

```
public class PrintStatements {
public static class GetStatements extends sdlParserBaseListener {
    StringBuilder statements = new StringBuilder();
     public void exitStatement(sdlParserParser.StatementContext ctx){               
            statements.append(ctx.getText());
            statements.append("\n");                        
        }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

String inputFile = null;
if ( args.length>0 ) inputFile = args[0];
InputStream is = System.in;
if ( inputFile!=null ) {
    is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
}
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
sdlParserLexer lexer = new sdlParserLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
sdlParserParser parser = new sdlParserParser(tokens);
ParseTree tree = parser.s();

// create a standard ANTLR parse tree walker
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
// create listener then feed to walker
GetStatements loader = new GetStatements();
walker.walk(loader, tree);        // walk parse tree   

System.out.println(loader.statements.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get original text of an Antlr rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443860/get-original-text-of-an-antlr-rule)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved this problem by using  tokens.getText() in the upper level of the statement, like this:

```
public void exitE(sdlParserParser.EContext ctx) {
    TokenStream tokens = parser.getTokenStream();
    String Stmt = null;
    Stmt = tokens.getText(ctx.statement());
                ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new with ANTLR, so maybe i'm wrong with something...

I don't know easy way to do this but you can try something like this.
In your grammar file you probably have something like this:

```
WS  :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') 
{   
    if (!preserveWhitespacesAndComments) {
      skip();
    } else {
       $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
}
```

This lexer rule tells parser to ignore whitespaces. More exactly this tokens are sent on HIDDEN channel (parser don't see them). If you comment this lines of code

```
WS  :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') 
{   
    if (!preserveWhitespacesAndComments) {
    //   skip();
    } else {
      //  $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
}
```

all whitespaces will be sent to parser but then you need to rewrite parser rules so he can expect whitespaces at any place.

```
Object(EXPECT WHITESPACE)o(EXPECT WHITESPACE)=(EXPECT WHITESPACE)Ma.addToObj(r1);
```

Otherwise parser will report errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of two things:

- The ability to take file position data for the first and last tokens accepted by a statement parse (either the lexemes or the tree nodes should do), and go to the source file, and extract the text.  That will get you the original whitespace.
- A prettyprinter, which will regenerate text from the AST, inserting appropriate whitespacing. See my SO answer on how to build a prettyprinter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834775/120163).

Answer (score 0):

in terms of Antlr4 and Python3, the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758827/3171310) looks as follows:

```
def exitSomeDecl(self, ctx: yourParser.SomeDeclContext):
    start_index = ctx.start.tokenIndex
    stop_index = ctx.stop.tokenIndex
    user_text = self.token_stream.getText(interval=(start_index, stop_index))
```

here, the `self.token_stream: CommonTokenStream` is assigned during init:

```
    input_stream = FileStream(file_name)
    lexer = sdplLexer(input_stream)
    token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
```